# Exceptions in validation

Tags: c#, exception

I currently have some code that delibratly throws an exception if the user sends me data that fails validation (see below). I like it because im sure any errors in the application are caught and handled. A am however worried the code being slow as throwing exceptions takes a lot of memory. Im also worried it might be "bad code". Whats your advice? Thanks

```
  public class BTAmendAppointmentRequest
    {
        public DataLayer.WebserviceMessage AddBTAmendAppointmentRequest(DataLayer.BTAmendAppointmentRequest req)
        {
            DataLayer.WebserviceMessage rsp = new DataLayer.WebserviceMessage();
            try
            {

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.AppointmentReference))
                    req.AppointmentReference = req.AppointmentReference.Trim();

                if (req.OrderRequestID < 1 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.AppointmentReference))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Amend appointment failed, you must supply a valid appointment reference and order reference");
                }

        ...Do other stuff
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rsp = new Service.WebserviceErrorMessage(ex);
            }


            return rsp;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *expecting* these errors, you should return error messages to the user, not throw exceptions.

Reserve exceptions to *exceptional* situations.

Apart from being expensive, the meaning of an exception, the semantics are that of something exceptional having happened. Validation failing is *not* exceptional, it is *expected*.

Having said that, seeing as you are on a web service, an exception is a reasonable thing to do, assuming you also validate *before* the service call. It is reasonable since a web service can be called by *anything* - validation may not have happened, and such errors *should* be exceptional. Additionally, at least with .NET web services, web exceptions are probably the best way to communicate such things back to the client.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why?

Comment: Why what? Exactly which part of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should be considered as last resort error trap. They should be "exceptional". Data input errors are not exceptions - they are very common, expected events. You shoudl handle validation issues with validation controls or processes, that handle them - display an error message and do not let the processing continue.

Your other problem is that you cannot easily do full form validation if the first error you encounter throws an exception. If I was filling out a form where each error was separately highlighted, I would give up very quickly. You need to be able to validate and display ALL errors on a page, and not permit progress without validation succeeding.

Comment: As a web service, you should be validating the data before it is passed to the service. If you need to do validation here as well, validate the whole data set, and return an exception if there are problems. But this should still be exceptional.

Comment: Input validation should have occurred before the service, but "data that fails validation" is not limited to input quality.

Comment: @Adam - yes accepted, but the example appears to be input data. And the principles still apply I think, that data validation should be done as a whole, and prevent progress.

Comment: Indeed, whether or not to use exceptions is personal taste.  Personally, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with Oded in that exceptions should only be used for stuff you aren't expecting.  The other way to look at it is with using an errors collection, you are able to validate a larger batch instead of throwing an exception on the first problem.  This can be more usable for the person consuming your service.

In the case of web services, I would package the entire response in a custom response object, which features a return code.  This allows you to have a return code of error, and then encapsulate an errors collection in the response object.